# В какой области памяти хранятся статические поля класса?

Tags: память, java

В какой области памяти хранятся статические поля класса? Stack? Heap? ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В области Permanent Generation (с java 8 Permanent Generation заменен на MetaSpace который находится в разделе non-heap (стэк)). Хотя стоит заметить, что для самих объектов, на которые ссылаются статические поля, память может быть выделена и в других областях heap.