# Как в java хранятся статические поля?

Tags: java

Как в java хранятся статические поля класса? Знаю что был такой вопрос. [(JAVA) В какой области памяти хранятся статические поля класса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230726/java-%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)
Но там сказано что они хранятся в Permanent Generation. А в java 8 ведь он заменен на MetaSpace? Хранятся ли они теперь в MetaSpace? Если да, объясните пожалуйста, почему так? Ведь MetaSpace это область, в которой хранятся метаданные? А статические поля не являются же метаданными.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> А в java 8 ведь он заменен на MetaSpace?

Да, если мы говорим о HotSpot jvm.

> Хранятся ли они теперь в MetaSpace?

Да

> Если да, объясните пожалуйста, почему так? Ведь MetaSpace это область,
>   в которой хранятся метаданные?

MetaSpace - это та же PermGen, только с плюшкой в виде динамического расширения. В Permanent Generation предельный размер зависел от многих факторов: количество классов, методов, размер пула констант и т.п. Теперь размер мета пространства ограничен лишь размеров доступной памяти. Если хотим поменять, то юзаем флаг `MaxMetaspaceSize`.

Таким образом исключили возможность выпадения `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Ну да, если вы упрётесь в предел RAM, или в предел заданный в `MaxMetaspaceSize`, то исключение будет.

> А статические поля не являются же метаданными.

Ммм. Если посмотреть книгу [Java Data Objects](https://books.google.ru/books?id=vUf7AAAAQBAJ&hl=ru), то [там](https://books.google.ru/books?id=dTr7AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT123&lpg=PT123&dq=java%20static%20fields%20is%20metadata&source=bl&ots=vQDcYjaFL7&sig=SmcK-1SaI2NbOuMnBJpHeFKu2J0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAmoVChMI6-WUxrqSyQIVRNwsCh2KZglj#v=onepage&q=java%20static%20fields%20is%20metadata&f=false) сказано, что статические поля - это мета данные.

Answer (score 4):

Ответ @Suvitruf вообще говоря запутывает. Скажем, вы заводите статическое поле:

```
class MyClass {
    static List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

В этом случае в Metaspace будет храниться только ссылка на объект `ArrayList`. А сам `ArrayList`, естественно, будет в обычной куче (как и в предыдущих версиях Java). Не забывайте, что вы можете потом в любой момент сделать хоть обычное нестатическое поле, хоть локальную переменную и присвоить тот же объект: `List<String> var = MyClass.myList;`.

Вообще Metaspace — это off-heap память, а Java-объекты всегда располагаются в куче. Даже если ссылка на них есть из off-heap региона.

Comment: Правильно я понял что если создать локальную переменную и присвоить ей ссылку на статическое поле, то эта локальная переменная попадет как ей и положено, в стек?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров, локальная переменная (в смысле, сама ссылка на объект) может храниться где угодно на усмотрение JIT-компилятора, это неспецифицировано. В 64-битной VM часто локальные переменные попадают в регистры. Оптимизатор может вообще решить, что эта переменная не нужна, например.